# Laravel Eloquent and time comparrison

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I was trying to use an advanced where to pull entries using Laravel Eloquent that included a date comparison. While I found another way to run a date comparison (another foreach after I pulled the records), it still bugs me why this wasn't working. Just curious if anyone else had some feedback on it. Here's what I had:

```
$surveys = Survey::where('is_published', 1)
                ->whereNull('closes_at')
                ->orWhere('closes_at', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                ->whereHas('assigned', function($q){
                    $q->where('employee_id', Session::get('employee_id'));
                })->orWhere('assigned_to_all', 1)
                ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->get();
```

So what I was trying to do was pull all surveys that were:

- published
- either they were assigned to everyone OR it was specifically assigned to them (the 'assigned' module).
- where closes at (deadline) was either null or not closed.

If I pull it from the database, it's fine. Just couldn't pull the right ones using Eloquent. I tried a couple different date calls and none of them were working.

Anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pulling surveys where 'is_published'= 1 and ( closes_at was null or closes_at > current time or assigned_to_all = 1 or specifically assigned to them). Try this:

```
$surveys = Survey::where('is_published', 1)
            ->where(function($query){
                $query->whereNull('closes_at')
                    ->orWhere('closes_at', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            })
            ->where(function($query){
                $query->whereHas('assigned', function($q){
                        $q->where('employee_id', Session::get('employee_id'));
                    })
                ->orWhere('assigned_to_all', 1);
            })
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Oh my gosh. That was totally it! Worked when I put it in place. That was really bugging me. Thanks!!